# How to open PDF/xml which stored in a SQLite file?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I open them which have already stored in SQLite ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that it is better to store files as files rather than blob fields in SQLite, and to keep their filenames in DB.

But if you want to proceed with blob fields, you should write byte[] from that blob field to a temporary file with FileOutputStream. After that just open that file.

Answer (score -2):

You can't store files in a SQLite Database. You can store links to files in a SQLite database or you can store binary data.

I recommend reading how SQLite works.

Comment: But I had a sqlite and there are really PDF and XML file in it by checking by sqlite viewer.  The datatype is blob.